# ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1$mcLL$sp

Tags: scala

Hope someone can help me :)

I'm playing around with [Rowz](http://www.github.com/twitter/Rowz) which I'm busy changing to use the newest Scala and Sbt (to help me evaluate Rowz in my environment and also just as a learning exercise).  Now I'm getting the following error which I'm struggling to resolve:

```
Starting rowz (it's kinda quiet at the moment)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$mcLL$sp
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at Evaluator__92455c9cf893b1375b64dc2cae2905dd9718fe77_409351476$$anon$2$$anon$11.<init>((inline):48)
    at Evaluator__92455c9cf893b1375b64dc2cae2905dd9718fe77_409351476$$anon$2.<init>((inline):48)
    at Evaluator__92455c9cf893b1375b64dc2cae2905dd9718fe77_409351476.apply((inline):38)
    at Evaluator__92455c9cf893b1375b64dc2cae2905dd9718fe77_409351476.apply((inline):1)
    at com.twitter.util.Eval.applyProcessed(Eval.scala:197)
    at com.twitter.util.Eval.applyProcessed(Eval.scala:189)
    at com.twitter.util.Eval.apply(Eval.scala:135)
    at com.twitter.util.Eval.apply(Eval.scala:169)
    at com.twitter.rowz.Main$.main(Main.scala:16)
    at com.twitter.rowz.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1$mcLL$sp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 22 more
```

Any ideas?

I'm using the latest Scala (currently 2.10.1) and Sbt (currently 0.12.3)

The stacktrace mentions Twitter's util-eval project.  I have the latest version.  In my Sbt file:
    libraryDependencies += "com.twitter"    %% "util-eval"      % "[6.2.4,)"

And this then retrieves:

- /lib_managed/jars/com.twitter/util-core_2.10/util-core_2.10-6.3.0.jar
- /lib_managed/jars/com.twitter/util-eval_2.10/util-eval_2.10-6.3.0.jar
- /lib_managed/jars/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/scala-reflect-2.10.1.jar

The file in question: [Eval class on Twitter's github](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala#L175)

As the latter is subject to change the code in question is as follows with the error occurring on the last line:

```
  **
   * same as apply[T], but does not run preprocessors.
   */
  def applyProcessed[T](className: String, code: String, resetState: Boolean): T = {
    val cls = compiler(wrapCodeInClass(className, code), className, resetState)
    cls.getConstructor().newInstance().asInstanceOf[() => Any].apply().asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: The scala/Function1$mcLL$sp part is also interesting.  I'm used to Java where an internal class is designated with a $ subsequent to the main  class.  Not too familiar with Scala internals to know what the double ampersand could possibly imply...

Comment: grepping the scala-library jar, it seems `Function1$mcLL$sp` existed in 2.8.2, and disappeared 2.9.x. It is an internal class representing `Function1` with the `apply` method specialized for `long`. More importantly, this means you have some code that was compiled against 2.8.x in your dependencies!

Comment: +1 thanks. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again :)

Comment: sure, there you go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grepping the scala-library jar, it seems that `Function1$mcLL$sp` existed in 2.8.2, and disappeared 2.9.x.

It is an internal class representing `Function1` with the `apply` method specialized for `long`.

**More importantly, this means you have some code that was compiled against 2.8.x in your dependencies.**

You should go through all your dependencies and make sure they all target 2.10.x.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use specialization. It's broken. I have seen these kind of errors repeatedly, after I already published libraries that were successfully compiled with specialization (which is enabled by default).

Until specialization is thoroughly fixed, I recommend to compile all projects with

```
-no-specialization
```

Comment: Sadly, I have to back this up.

Comment: +1 thanks. To use -no-specialization with sbt: `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-no-specialization")`